# Cannot call Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

please look at the following sample code:

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
    function myfun()
    {
        alert('hi');
    }
       </script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <h1> Hello </h1>
    <input type="button" value="MyButton" onClick="myfun()"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I run this using php, and when I click on the button, the alert box doesn't come up. However, if I write `onclick="alert(hi')"` it works fine. What might be the reason?

Comment: can you please post the full code?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, which is a server side language. Is this the original code from the "view source" view of your browser? What errors do you get in the Javascript console?

Comment: your example code works. post your real code

Comment: @Pekka - just read his post below the code example ...

Comment: This is actually working for me using W3C's Tryit Editor. Let me mess with it in jsFiddle... Edit: Still works d00d.

Comment: its ajax content, i cannot find this code in view page source. server side language is php. This itself is not working in my browser.

Comment: Is the button AJAX content? You may have to use something like livequery to make it work. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery

Comment: @nikhil please post the AJAX code, especially what is executed in the `success` method of it. What you posted **is** valid and gives us no clue of the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

   <body>
        <h1> Hello </h1>
    <input type="button" value="MyButton" onClick="alert('hi')"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Missing a ' in your code...

Comment: I thought he said that if he uses the `alert('hi')` it works, which suggests the missing apostrophe is a typo, not the problem?

Comment: @David Thomas -:-) you know what they say about assumptions in our market...http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wg4trPZFUwc

Comment: Pretty sure he needs to do more than alert hi