# Cannot call custom-made Javascript function

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot call Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442514/cannot-call-javascript-function)

[Cannot call Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442514/cannot-call-javascript-function)

I exactly have the same problem as the link above.
but I still don't know the solution to the problem

Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: exactly the same problem as the link I post above.

Comment: but find no solution in that post...

Comment: oh...wrong clicks on "great comment" button lol

Comment: You say "exactly the same problem"... but are you using the exact same code?

Comment: @Matt but are you using the exact same code?<---YES!

Comment: @user988988 — The reason there is no solution in the other question is because *the code works as written* (as the comments on that question say).

Comment: in the link above, no one solves the problem there! this is exactly my problem too!

Comment: @Quentin if I custom-made a function that only contain the alert('abc'), then set onclick = "thatfunction()" for my button, no alert is popped out when I click it. while if I set onclick = "alert('abc')", then the button works

Comment: @user988988 — still cannot reproduce, [this code just works](http://jsfiddle.net/xjceT/)

Comment: @user988988 if that's true then it means you have **done it wrong** but we cannot help if you don't post your code here!

Comment: easiest flag in my life, he even provided the dup link

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there aren't any invisible elements in front of the `input` tag that are causing problems. Also make sure that, if there's event propagation, earlier click events are preventing default behavior.

The function syntax in the related question is accurate, and does work on at least my local machine (Safari).